# Taking an ImmutableCollection as parameter versus creating a local copy

Tags: java, guava

When using Guava's a [ImmutableCollection](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableCollection.html) as a parameter for a function is it better to require an `ImmutableCollection` as parameter type:

```
void <T> foo(ImmutableCollection<T> l)
```

or should the function take a `Collection<T>` and create an immutable collection itself as in

```
void <T> foo(Collection<T> l)
{
    ImmutableCollection<T> l2 = ImmutableCollection.copyOf(l);

    // ...
}
```

The first version seems preferable because the caller is sure that the map he passes to the function is not modified by it. But the first version requires client code with a collection to call `copyOf()`, that is:

```
Collection collection = map.values();
foo(ImmutableCollection.copyOf(collection));

// instead of simply

foo(collection);
```

PS: This is not completely true, since `ImmutableCollection` does not have `copyOf()` but `ImmutableList` and `ImmutableSet` do.

Comment: The second version will also leave your function signature independent of Guava.

Comment: Not to mention all the code duplication if you force every caller to do the wrapping himself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that it depends on what the `foo` function is supposed to do with the collection argument.

- If `foo` is going to read the collection elements, then `void <T> foo(Collection<T> l)` is preferable, because it leaves the decision to the caller.
- If `foo` is going to incorporate the collection into the state of some object, then an immutable collection may be preferable.  However, we then need to ask ourselves whether it should be the `foo` method's responsibility to deal with this, or the caller's responsibility.

There isn't a single right (or "best practice") answer to this.  However, using `ImmutableCollection` as the parameter's formal type could result in complexity and/or unnecessary copying *in some cases*.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the guava docs: ["copyOf is smarter than you think."](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/ImmutableCollectionsExplained)

So you can use the generic `Collection` interface with no regrets for performance.

Whether the copy is necessary (rather than a function comment) depends, in my view, on how long you're holding on to the data.

Comment: The point is that `ImmutableCollection` offers stronger guarantees than just `Collection` and that the caller might want to rely on you not changing the collection.

Comment: I understand that motivation, but I'd be hesitant to impose that requirement on the caller.  An overload would provide the code guarantee to those interested, at the expense of a larger api.

Answer (score 0):

Use the more generic `Collection` interface; it's much better for you to write the call once than to require all of the clients to do so on every call. If you're really concerned about performance, and profiling shows it to be an issue, you could do a class check on the incoming collection to see whether you can avoid the copy.

Comment: It is not all the callers, but only those which do not already use an `ImmutableCollection`.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what foo is doing. Most probably it simply reads the collection values in which case it does not need to make a copy of it, especially immutable one.

Answer (score 0):

The one advantage of using `ImmutableCollection` is that the method guarantees that it will not modify the collection. But then that guarantee is to the user only, the platform does not understand it, so you might as well express it in comments or a custom annotation.

Comment: But callers are much more likely to notice (compared to a comment).

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann yes, that is why I am conflicted whether it is a good idea :)